# change master page <a href link from content page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

i have this on my master.page

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first" runat="server" id="Li2">
        <a runat="server" id="A1" href="../NewEntry.aspx">Create a New Entry</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

when i go to content page ("NewEntry.aspx") i want the link name to be changed to "Update Entry"

```
<ul class="menu">
     <li class="first" runat="server" id="Li2">
         <a runat="server" id="A1" href="../UpdateEntry.aspx">Update Entry</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

any feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the link an asp:Hyperlink. Then have the master page expose a function or property:

```
public void SetLink(string href, string text)
{
    A1.NavigateURL = href;
    A1.Text = text;
}
```

Call the function from the main page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hyperlink control `<asp:hyperlink>` and set the url as well as the text values.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend handling this as a HyperLink control as others have mentioned. If for some reason you must handle this as a server-side HTML anchor, you can access it using the following code from your webform code-behind:

```
HtmlAnchor link = (HtmlAnchor)(this.Master).FindControl("A1");
link.InnerText = "Update Entry";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a content place holder where you have "Create a New Entry". Leave that as the default inside that place holder, and only in the content page set content for it to Update Entry.